# Difference between event Listeners and event Subscribers in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm actually learning Symfony, regarding the events, in fact I do not see any difference between a simple listener and a subscriber, the two are doing the same thing, but surely, there is a difference while symfony developers have developed two ways for listening to an event.

I did a research to discover this difference but I did not find a clear and convincing answer .

What is the main difference between a listener and a subscriber? Which one is the most used and what is its advantage over the other?And how to know which to use a simple listener or a subscriber?

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11031459/2661253

Answer (score 8):

[Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#listeners-or-subscribers)

> Listeners and subscribers can be used in the same application
>   indistinctly. The decision to use either of them is usually a matter
>   of personal taste. However, there are some minor advantages for each
>   of them:
>
> **Subscribers** are easier to reuse because the knowledge of the events is
>   kept in the class rather than in the service definition. This is the
>   reason why Symfony uses subscribers internally
>
> **Listeners** are more
>   flexible because bundles can enable or disable each of them
>   conditionally depending on some configuration value.